# Dieline and .eps file: Clipping Mask

Tags: adobe-illustrator, clipping-mask

I create a simple dieline, wrapping around is a .eps file (freepix by Creative Hat), but I cant use clipping mask to wrap.

[image]

[image: 2.jpg]

Appreciate, if someone can point me in the right direction?

Comment: It would appear as though the clipping mask **path** is not *one object* but rather a series of unconnected paths. That's may be the problem.

Comment: Hi Scott, yes! ive solved the problem... for those that have the same problem, just right click on the path, there is a flyout menu, just click on "join"

Comment: Thanks! Scott for the reply, appreciate! :) Have a great day ahead! :)

Answer (score 1):

It would appear as though the clipping mask path is not one object but rather a series of unconnected paths. That is most likely the problem.

Clipping masks should be a **single** path or **single** compound path.

You'll need to **join the disjointed segments** into one continual path.

Answer (score -1):

A clipping mask is a team of layers to which a mask is used. The bottommost layer, or base layer, defines the noticeable boundaries of the entire team. For example, mean you have a form in the base layer, a picture in the layer above it, and message in the upper layer. If the photograph, as well as message, show up just through the form synopsis in the base layer, they likewise take on the opacity of the base layer.

You can organize just succeeding layers. The name of the base layer in the group is underlined, and also the thumbnails for the superior layers are indented. In addition, the overlapping layers show the clipping mask icon.

Comment: Welcome to **GD.SE** - please take a peek at [tour] and [ask] and [answer] a question to get a sense of our community. I think there may be some translation issues here, as this answer as initially written is almost incomprehensible - perhaps some further editing would help?

Comment: This is an answer explaining how clipping masks work in **Photoshop**. The question is **specifically** asking about Illustrator. Using Illustrator all the information you've posted is entirely inaccurate.